# Compare property between two tables

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do something pretty simple but for some reason I got a little tangled up. I have two tables `userTbl` and `productivityTbl` connected by the `userCode` column.

The goal is to go over the `productivityTbl` and within that go over the `userTbl` to get into the variable the user's job code (in the user's table there is `UserPermission` which describes the user's job number), then do an action on the received role number.

The problem is, the code doesn't know how to convert the object to the type of table. I tried to make in advance that the object would be of the table type but that didn't help either.

I'm sure I probably haven’t explored all the ways but would love to get guidance on the subject.

Here is my code: (I deleted what was irrelevant)

```
public static List<object> getTotalWorkPerMonth(int nextMonth)
{
    using (Model2 db = new Model2())
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime sixMonthsBack = today.AddMonths(-6);

        while (sixMonthsBack < today)
        {
            foreach (var item in db.ProductivityTbl.ToList())
            {
                if (item.Date.Value.Month == sixMonthsBack.Month)
                {
                    // Here's my problem, when the userRoll is of type var then the code
                    // gets the header line but he does not let 
                    // me do in switch user.UserPermission and when the userRoll is 
                    // of type userTbl then he requires to do a conversion 
                    // from LINQ to userTbl and does not get the header line.

                    var userRoll = db.UserTbl.Where(u => u.UserCode == item.UserCode);

                    switch (userRoll.UserPermission)
                    {
                        // some code
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to it and I guess it's rookie issues and I'm still happy for your help.
Thanks for the reference, appreciate

Comment: What is the type of UserPermission, is it primitive data type or it's object? See if pattern matching [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) would assist you for what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude here.  I just want you to appear professional to coworkers/teachers/etc.  If you want a user's role, it is spelled "role".  Roll is a biscuit or action.

Also, any time you .tolist a dataset, it's not a data table anymore and you are now using linq for objects.  You can't use them both at the same time.

Comment: Hey, I know it's not perfect, I'm still a student and slowly learning how to write in a cleaner and better way.
Thanks for the comment, I took note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that the LINQ statement below would give you a unique record:

```
var userRoll = db.UserTbl.Where(u => u.UserCode == item.UserCode);
```

Then you might want to try something like this

```
var userRoll = db.UserTbl.Where(u => u.UserCode == item.UserCode).FirstOrDefault();
if (userRoll != null)
{
    switch (userRoll.UserPermission)
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```